# Entering Username and Password for SMTP Server

Tags: ibm-information-server

I am using Change Data Capture 6.3 with DB2 and I try to set email notification. This is the instruction from the manual

To set an e-mail notification

Note: This information is applicable to InfoSphere CDC for DB2 UDB, InfoSphere CDC for Microsoft SQL Server version 6.0, InfoSphere CDC for PointBase, and InfoSphere CDC for Teradata.
1. Click Configuration → Datastores.
2. Right-click on a datastore and select Notifications.
3. Depending on whether you want InfoSphere CDC to detect events on the source datastore or on the target datastore, click the Source tab or the Target tab.
4. Select a category from Notification Categories.
5. Select the INTERNET MAIL box.
6. Type the host name of your outgoing mail server in the SMTP Mail Host box.
7. Type the e-mail address that you want to notify in the Alert Account box. Use a semicolon to separate multiple e-mail addresses or specify a distribution list from your e-mail application.
8. Type your e-mail address in the Sender Mail Address box.
9. Type your e-mail password in the Sender Mail Password box.

But when I go to the notification windows as the manual says, There are not Sender Mail Address and Sender Mail Password box. There are only SMTP Mail Host and Alert Account boxes. So I can not enter the username and password for my smtp server. Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Attached is a screenshot of what the dialog should look like if you’re in the correct location for configuring email notifications as described in the docs. As you can see here, there’s a field for smtp mail host, alert account and sender email address and password.

If your dialog looks different, can you verify the version of Management Console you have by clicking Help - >About? You should have 6.3. If that doesn’t resolve the problem, can you post a screenshot of what you’re seeing?